# Programmatically change cell style

Tags: cells

I have been trying unsuccessfully to programmatically change a cell style in order to change it to a text-style cell as I just want to put some text in it that should not be evaluated:

```
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], Evaluatable -> False]
```

I tried all kinds of other ideas to get this done but nothing worked.

Is there anybody that can help?

Comment: Linked topic answers you question. Let me know in case I missed the point.

Comment: You're right Kuba, it answers my question. Thanks!